# Rails Activeadmin : Check boxes values are not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Model

```
 # certification.rb

class Certification < ActiveRecord::Base

 extend Enumerize
 enumerize :certification_type, in: [:SEO, :CRM]

end
```

My admin file

```
 # admin/certification.rb

ActiveAdmin.register Certification do
   permit_params :name,
                 :certification_type,

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
       f.inputs "Certifications" do
         f.input :name, :label => 'Nom'
         f.input :certification_type, :label => 'Type',
                                    as: :check_boxes
      end
     f.actions
  end
end
```

The problem is with the `certification_type` field.
When I tick one type in my activeadmin page, the entry isn't saved in the database. But when I change `as: :check_boxes` with a `as: :select`, it works.

Do you know if there is a reason ?

Thank you

Comment: When you use checkboxes and submit the form, what is passed in the request parameters? (you can see this in logs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use checkboxes here, as checkboxes allow to select multiple values for one field, but you didn't specify `multiple: true` on the `enumerize` (because you don't need this, I guess). So you should use radio buttons, as they allow to select only one of many values (similar to `select`).

Try to change `as: :check_boxes` to `as: :radio`:

```
 f.input :certification_type, :label => 'Type', as: :radio
```